# Differential Equation @ 2nd Order

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve this? $$\dfrac{d^2x}{dt^2}=-kx^2$$

I need it in physics problem.https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/60202/non-shm-oscillatory-motion/     Though solved without it but still it would be better to have this.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/166981

Comment: @doraemonpaul That one is easy but here it is=> $\ddot x + kx^2=0$m The $+$ is creating problem.

Answer (score 2):

The differential equation is not easy to solve. The usual trick is to let $v=\frac{dx}{dt}$. Multiply both sides by $2\frac{dx}{dt}$.

On the left-hand side we have the derivative of $v^2$. On the right, we have the derivative of $-\frac{2k}{3}x^3$. So $v^2=-\frac{2k}{3}x^3+C$. We end up with a separable equation. Unfortunately, unless we are very lucky and $C=0$, we end up with something that cannot be integrated in elementary terms.

Comment: And we are not fortunate enough! It is a Oscillatory motion and V is max at x=0 and visa-versa.

Comment: There is a related trick of finding a differential equation for $t$ in terms of $x$. But I do not think it leads to a better result: elliptic functions are unavoidable.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=-kx^2$$

$$\implies \frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)=-kx^2$$

$$\implies d\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right) =-kx^2dx$$

Integrating either sides, $$ \frac{\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2}2=\frac{-kx^3}3+c $$

$$\implies \frac{dx}{dt}=\pm \sqrt{\frac{6c-2kx^3}3}$$

Comment: Are you sure miultiplying wit dx makes it go inside the d() on LHS.Before integrating?

Comment: @exploringnet, it will be clearer if you put $v=\frac{dx}{dt}$

Comment: and is the last one integrable for $c\not=0$

Answer (score 0):

One solution will be of the form $x=at^n$ so substitute that in to get $an(n-1)t^{n-2}=-ka^2t^{2n}$.  This gives $2n=n-2, n=-2$  Then $an(n-1)=6a=-ka^2$ so $a=-\frac 6k$.  Unfortunately as the equation is not linear, you can't use this to get all solutions.

Answer (score -1):

I think this might be part of the solution

let x(t) be a Taylor series

the co-efficients of the taylor series contain x(0), x'(0), x''(0) ... etc 
I think these can be derived from d2xdt2=−kx2 and some initial conditions for x(0) = a, and x'(0) = b

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRi4k.jpg

The final recurrence relation can be used to compute the x(0), x'(0), x''(0) co-efficients which can then be used to construct the taylor series for x(t)

It may not be nice but I believe it will work ...

Comment: also need some boundary conditions

Comment: actually I'm thinking now more along the lines of a taylor series solution

Comment: This would probably be better as a comment.

Comment: What is x(0) = ?
also x'(0) = ?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://math.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://math.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: I think I have the solution, I'm just having trouble with Latex at the moment ....

Comment: let x(t) be a taylor series, the co-effiecients of the series will be x(0), x'(0), x''(0) ... etc these can be derived from the initial equation and some initial conditions {x(0)= a x'(0) = b)}

Comment: This should now answer the question

Comment: This is similar to this problem http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/6/de3f.png/