# General solution to ODE $ y''-Ay^5=0 $

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

What is the solution of $$ y''-Ay^5=0  $$
I got the solution $ y = {(3/4A)}^{1/4} x^{-1/2}$ using trial and error but how to solve this type of problem in general?

Comment: It's a nonlinear equation and so asking for a 'general' solution is going to be tricky/not possible. Without a superposition principle, writing down an expression with the some number of unknowns that can describe every possible behavior of the solutions is mostly doomed before it even starts. In what context are you interested in solutions to this ODE? It is likely possible to find good approximate descriptions depending on what you need it for.

Comment: This is a solution if you forget possible integration constants, I suppose.

Comment: $A$ is a matrix?

Comment: You can use the same way as I showed for other similiar question.http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/166981/closed-form-solutions-of-ddot-xt-xtn-0/167025#167025

Comment: A is a scalar constant.

Answer (score 3):

Let us try to replace the trial and error approach and **assume** that $y=ax^k$; so, replacing, we get $$a (k-1) k x^{k-2}-a^5 A x^{5 k}=0$$ So, you could set $k-2=5k$ (that is to say $k=-\frac 12$ and $a(k-1)k=a^5 A$ which leads to five different solutions for $a$, two of them being imaginary, and one of them being $0$. Among the real, one solution is your.

But, as said in comments, this is just a very particular solution.

The problem is very complex as showed in the link provided by Mathlover.

Answer (score 2):

Set it to $$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = Ay^5$$

If we multiply this ODE by $2 \frac{dy}{dx}$ we get
$2 \frac{dy}{dx} \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = 2A y^5 \frac{dy}{dx}$
Thus $\left( \frac{dy}{dx} \right)^2 = \frac{Ay^6}{6} + K$.
Now, in the simple case (where we say have initial conditions such as) when $y = 1$, $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ so $K = 0$. 
i.e. $\displaystyle \left( \frac{dy}{dx} \right)^2 = \frac{y^6}{3} $
so  $ \left( \frac{dy}{dx} \right) = \frac{y^3}{\sqrt{3}} $ 
Separating, $\frac{dy}{y^3} = \frac{dx}{\sqrt{3}}$ so
$ - \frac{1}{2} y^{-2} = \frac{x}{\sqrt{3}} + A$. 
As $y = 1$ when $x = 0$, $A = -\frac{1}{2}$ so
$ - \frac{1}{2} y^{-2} = \frac{x}{\sqrt{3}} -\frac{1}{2}$ 
i.e.  $ = \left( 1 - \frac{2x}{\sqrt{3}} \right)^{-1/2}$.

That would be a specific solution (which I've seen before which is why I mention it here, however life isn't that simple and you don't mention any inital conditions so it would amount to solving (which is trickier but not impossible)
\begin{equation}
\frac{dy}{dx} = \sqrt{\frac{Ay^{6}}{6} + K}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

In this equation, $x$ is missing and its solution is routine (check any DE textbooks). Let $u=y'$ and then $u'=y''$. Treating $u$ as a function of $y$ and then noting
$$ u'=\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{du}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{du}{dy}y'=\frac{du}{dy}u $$
we have
$$ \frac{du}{dy}u=Ay^5 $$
which is a separable DE whose solution is standard. I think you can handle it.